# Difference between materialised view and table which is refreshed incremental

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

There is question that why we create materialised view. I have a table and to refresh the table incrementally I have dbms job which merges the data from different table into this.  So it is equivalent to materialised view with fast refresh. Is there any difference? Which implementation  is better in above two cases?

Comment: Which is better? Using a built in feature of your database system (that has been extensively tested and debugged) or writing code (that you have to debug) to approximate the same feature?

Comment: Using a built in feature is better.

Answer (score 0):

**Materialized view** can  be refreshed **on demand** or on refresh frequency. It can consist of a join of two or more tables.

> When creating a materialized view, you have the option of specifying whether the refresh occurs ON DEMAND or ON COMMIT. In the case of ON COMMIT, the materialized view is changed every time a transaction commits, thus ensuring that the materialized view always contains the latest data. Alternatively, you can control the time when refresh of the materialized views occurs by specifying ON DEMAND. In the case of ON DEMAND materialized views, the refresh can be performed with refresh methods provided in either the DBMS_SYNC_REFRESH or the DBMS_MVIEW packages:

Here's the documentation [link](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/refresh.htm)

Also materialized views can be refreshed incrementally.

**Your Custom Solution**

Takes a lot of code and does not scale well.

Comment: Agreed about this, but this can be done with the table also. I can run the dbms job on schedule as well as manually. Or in case of manually I can execute the pl/sql block within dbms job to refresh the table. So manually is same as on demand in materialised view. The other case of ON COMMIT, I can schedule the dbms job to run on commit via dbms_scheduler.

Comment: The point is why would you want to write custom solution,  If there is a built in/tested functionality that performs well

Comment: Okay, but we cannot create materialized view in all cases. If I talk about performance, I don't know which will perform better in which case.

Answer (score 0):

Materialized views following [certain conventions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/basicmv.htm#i1007007) can be **fast refreshed** using a materialized view log. That means Oracle will only have to process actual changes in order to refresh the materialized view, where a merge operation would have to compare all rows every time. Therefore a materialized view would allow for much faster and more frequent refreshes especially with larger tables.

Comment: okay That's one difference, but the "certain conventions" or I can say "restrictions" are way too much. Adding to your point while refreshing through materialised view log, the updation is done by copying the database blocks from logs to table blocks. While merge is a DML , it will create undo space and then after firing commit block level operations are performed. In case of fast refresh, materialised view are better what about full refresh?In full refresh, Is the case is same for materialized view and truncate-load table?

Answer (score 0):

After lot of search I got something on materialised view which we can not do on normal table and it is query rewrite. Below is my finding.

```
SQL> GRANT GLOBAL QUERY REWRITE to mydbdba;

SQL> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW customers_mw ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS
SELECT COUNT(*) c,state_id FROM sg.customers GROUP BY state_id;

SQL> alter session set QUERY_REWRITE_ENABLED=TRUE;

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) c,state_id FROM sg.customers GROUP BY state_id;

Execution Plan

Plan hash value: 799451518


| Id | Operation | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time |

| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT | | 52 | 364 | 3 (0)| 00:00:01 |
| 1 | MAT_VIEW REWRITE ACCESS FULL| CUSTOMERS_MW | 52 | 364 | 3 (0)| 00:00:01 |

SQL> alter session set QUERY_REWRITE_ENABLED=FALSE;

Session altered.

SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) c,state_id FROM sg.customers GROUP BY state_id;

Execution Plan

Plan hash value: 1577413243


| Id | Operation | Name | Rows | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time |

| 0 | SELECT STATEMENT | | 52 | 156 | 327 (1)| 00:00:01 |
| 1 | HASH GROUP BY | | 52 | 156 | 327 (1)| 00:00:01 |
| 2 | TABLE ACCESS FULL| CUSTOMERS | 50000 | 146K| 326 (1)| 00:00:01 |
```

you can see in above example how a materialised view is used instead of scanning whole table again.